# Sage Pay Integration with a simple html form

Tags: html, forms, payment-gateway, opayo

I have a html form that works. I also have a sage pay account that works.

How would I go about simply posting the submissions from my form to my sage pay account?

I want it to work very much like a paypal pay now button works where the info and fields are posted to the sagepay account where the user will make a payment.

I have tried looking through the docs but my java/net knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Which integration are you trying to use? SERVER/DIRECT/FORM?

FORM is like PayPal express, you get a redirection to Sage Pay, customer pays and returns to your site.

You can find code samples here http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/form-integration

Pablo.